# Could not open input file: artisan

Tags: laravel

GitHub にある [laravel-forum](https://github.com/Team-Tea-Time/laravel-forum) というLaravelプロジェクトをセットアップしようとしたのですが、artisanファイルが含まれていないので以下のメッセージが表示されます。
こういう場合ってどうすればいいのでしょうか？

```
Could not open input file: artisan
```

原始的に、別に新規でLaravelプロジェクトを作り、そこにソースを移動するとかしか方法ないのでしょうか？

Comment: そのままcloneして使おうとしていますか？これはライブラリパッケージとなっているので、おそらく普通に使用するのであれば新規にLaravelプロジェクトを作成し、そこでドキュメントの通り `composer request` しましょう。

Answer (score 2):

これは Laravel プロジェクトではなく ”ライブラリ” です．
すでにある Laravel プロジェクトにインストールして使うものです．

GitHub の readme に Installation という見出しがあるので，それに従って導入すると良いでしょう．
ただし，このドキュメントには書いてありませんが，前提としてすでに Laravel プロジェクトが作ってある必要があります．

必要に応じて，以下を参照しローカル環境に新しく Laravel プロジェクトを作成してください．
https://readouble.com/laravel/10.x/ja/installation.html

Laravel のプロジェクトができたら，プロジェクトルートまでターミナルで移動し，以下のコマンドを実行します．（Step1）

```bash
composer require riari/laravel-forum:~5.0
```

そうすると， composer を使って laravel-forum がインストールされます．
composer.json の require を確認してみてください．laravel-forum が追加されていると思います．

次に，laravel-forum が提供するサービスプロバイダを登録する必要があるため， config/app.php の `providers` に，以下を追加します（Step1）

```php
TeamTeaTime\Forum\ForumServiceProvider::class,
```

次に，laravel-forum を利用するのに必要な設定を Laravel プロジェクトに生成するため以下のコマンドを実行します（Step2）

```bash
php artisan vendor:publish
```

artisan コマンドがちゃんと実行できたと思います．

Step3 以降は，ドキュメントに従ってご自分で進めてみてください．